# ASP.NET MVC 2 Setting User Control element properties with values in the ViewModel

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm not entirely sure this is possible, but what I am trying to do is set an element property within a user control to a value passed in via a ViewModel class.

for example, say I have the following ViewModel class

```
public class myViewModel
{    
    [DisplayName("Image URL")]
    public string URL { get; set; 
}
```

and then have the following defined on the top of my user control

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Project.ViewModels.myViewModel>"
```

why can I not do this to set the src property on an Image tag for example?

```
<img src="<%Model.URL%>" />
```

any help would be great, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you just miss an = before Model.URL?

e.g. `<img src="<%=Model.URL %>" />`